# Dynamic content (Textarea) inside a jQuery Accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, textarea, jquery-ui-accordion

The scenario is pretty straight-forward, I have a textarea within a jQuery accordion.  When I adjust the height of the text-area on my browser, the content of the current accordion overlaps to the accordion below.

```
<div class="accordion">
    <h3>Sec 1</h3>
    <div>
        <textarea></textarea>
        I move with the textarea
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <span>I am being overlapped :o</span>
</div>
```

-I encountered a similar issue with with dynamically appending content (e.g. ).  I overcame this with refreshing the accordion.

```
$(".accordion").accordion("refresh");
```

How can I handle resizing of text-areas? I don't want to capture the resize event as I have many text-areas and I don't want to keep track of all their initial dimensions.  Thanks!

**edit**

I realize now, by default accordion will create a scrollbar for 'overflowed' content.  I want my content to dynamically resize the height however, so I did an over-ride on the css

```
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-content {
        overflow: visible !important;
 }
```

Here is a working demo.

https://jsfiddle.net/normangr7/vebw8o0b/

Comment: For better understanding, Please provide a **working demo** (*code snippet,jsfiddle ...*)

Comment: okay.. first time using jsfiddle.. will upload soon

Comment: //jsfiddle.net/normangr7/vebw8o0b/

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/vebw8o0b/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `height : auto !important;` for `.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-content`

```
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-content {
  height :auto !important;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: visible !important;  
}
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/vebw8o0b/1

Comment: Thankyou! exactly what I needed.  I noticed however that now when i collapse the accordion, there is no animation, just instant.  Must be a trade-off for the auto-generated height.

Comment: Good, I have done small hack on `animate`.
try this. http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/vebw8o0b/3/

Comment: nice hack! much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I think your question's answer is here: [jQuery accordion w/input, how do you get the input to not close the accordion & still be able to control it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7664954/jquery-accordion-w-input-how-do-you-get-the-input-to-not-close-the-accordion) . In this topic, in first post, you can find very usefull jsfiddle codes: There are 4 textarea in the accordion and they are not overlapping.

By the way thanks for your question i was researching a method for fitting in my 7 textarea in a page, now i found the solution.

Comment: I had already viewed this.  I dont think it answers my question.  You can use my jsfiddle example to see what I mean. Thanks